# is it possible to have excel simplify a function with a variable?

Tags: excel

I want

```
=A1/(s+A1)
```

to just substitute the value in A1. I tried converting A1 to a string and using substitute but I get a #Name? error. I used

```
=SUBSTITUTE(wc/(s+wc),wc,TEXT(A1,"0"))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? the Substitute will work with a string, so it'd be (I think) `=Substitute("wc/(s+wc)","wc",text(A1,"0"))`.  Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You could create a named range named `wc` that is defined as `=Sheets1!$A$1`